# How to create reports in Excel or Word using Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Suppose there is a table with data and by certain criteria (for example by date) you need to generate a report as txt or xml. So here is how it can be implemented on Rails for example using JavaScript? Can I have any articles or better video lessons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like that:

create a method in the controller and define that in routes as a post request. like -

```
def report
  # some operation to generate the result 
  # assume that results is in @results instance variable
  respond_to do |format|
        format.xls {
          response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"report.xls\""
        }
      end
end
```

in the view add a form with that newly created route as form action.

```
<%= form_tag(report_path(format: :xls), method: 'post') do %>
    # define a submit button which will hit the report method
<% end %>
```

lastly create a `report.xls.erb` file which contains the table generated from the `@results` variable.

Hope it helps!

Comment: for this no gems are needed (like RubyXL)?

Comment: No gem required. Rails provides different `mime_types` like: pdf, xls etc. by default.